# if an integer is equal to one of the integers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, types, int, operand

```
int[] usedArray = new int[25];

Random generator = new Random ();

int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(2);

System.out.println(randomNumber);

if(randomNumber != usedArray){
app();
}

while(randomNumber == 0){
score();
question1();
System.out.println(randomNumber);
usedArray[1] = 1;
app();
}
```

error:'incompatible operand types int & int[]'

How can I say if this number is equal to a number within the array without getting an error?

Comment: Which number in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an `int` with an `int[]`, which is plain wrong. If you want to check if the array contains some integer, then you can do:

```
if (!Arrays.asList(usedArray).contains(randomNumber)) {
    app();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare a number with an array.

`if(randomNumber != usedArray)` should be `if(randomNumber != usedArray[i])` with `i` as the index.